# WPF Binding tp ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I'm having trouble getting a listview to bind to a ViewModel.  The code for my ViewModel is as follows:

```
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ObservableCollection<MyDataItemViewModel> dataToShow;

    public ObservableCollection<MyDataItemViewModel> DataToShow
    {
        get
        {
            return dataToShow;  // A breakpoint here is never hit
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel(ObservableCollection<MyDataItemViewModel> toShow)
    {
        dataToShow = toShow;   // A breakpoint here reveals that there is data

        RegisterCommands();
    }
...
```

My XAML is as follows:

```
    <ListView   Name="DataView"
                ...
                ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModel.DataToShow}">

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Number"
                        ...
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Details.Number}" />
                ...
```

The code for the `MyDataItemViewModel` class returns a public class called `Details`, which contains a number of properties, including `Number`.

The screen displays fine, but without any data.

Comment: Have you set the datacontext of your view?

Comment: Plz add the code how you set the datacontext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DataToShow}"
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!  I'm a little unclear as to why though.  I've seen data bound like this before, even where where class was not static.

Comment: The data context of `ListView` is `MyViewModel` instance. So, path `DataContext.DataToShow` is valid, but `DataContext.MyViewModel.DataToShow` is not, because `MyViewModel` class hasn't `MyViewModel` property. Also, you may look into Visual Studio output window to find binding errors.